How to cast reference to enum to reference to underyling type (int)?
I'm working on a deserializer. The problem is that we have a lot of enums and I'm not gonna create overloads for each one of them. So I tried to first break the reference to enum down to a reference to its underlying type, but somehow it won't compile:
Live demo
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>


enum class MyEnum : uint32_t
{
    one = 100,
    two,
};

auto deserialize(std::byte* addr, uint32_t& val)
{
    memcpy(&val, addr, sizeof(uint32_t));
}

int main()
{
    std::byte buf[4] = { std::byte{0x00}, std::byte{0x00}, std::byte{0x00}, std::byte{0x64}};

    MyEnum val;
    
    using underlying_type = std::underlying_type_t<decltype(val)>&;
    deserialize(buf, static_cast<underlying_type>(val));

    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

How can I get this to work?

but somehow it won't compile The compile error should be included into the question.

I am working on a deserializer...  Say you have a class X { std::string member; }. Do you know why this is wrong : static_cast<X>(buf)? If you don't (and even if you do) pickup a library to do binary serialization and deserialization for you (it is a harder problem than you think). (Compiler differences, Compiler settings, OS, endianness of your processor... all lead to "but it works on my machine", the static cast issue is UB in a lot of cases). At least read up on std::bit_cast or why you should use memcpy (instead of static_cast)

@PepijnKramer because of alignement? But how is that related to an enum? An enum is always represented as an integer type, but the length might vary. And I'm using memcpy ^^

@glades You will mostly be fine for enums. Unless you save data on one machine and try to read it back on another machine with different endianness (or differently size integers, not all machines are 32 bits). The real problem begins when you have classes with (non-trivial) constructors. static_cast will not start the lifetime of the objects (constructors will not be called).  So I just wanted to warn you, your probably fine now, but if you want to do more than just enums... there is a lot of details to get right ;)

So, assuming it is not a toy project,  you might want to switch to a library like flatbuffers, or protobuf and let that code take care of binary serialization/deserialization for you.

@PepijnKramer It's a production grade toy project ;)

Then you'd better learn to play with production grade toys... ehr tools, and techniques too :)

Forget it. If you have an enum type, writing to it as if it were of its underlying type violates the strict aliasing rule. It's not hard to make the code compile (just use reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast) but the behaviour will be undefined due to the strict aliasing violation.
You have to deserialize into a proper uint32_t and then copy its value into the destination enum, for example:
template <class Enum>
requires std::is_enum_v<Enum>
void deserialize(std::byte* addr, Enum& val)
{
    std::underlying_type_t<Enum> underlying;
    deserialize(addr, underlying);
    val = static_cast<Enum>(underlying);
}

Or, I mean, why not just memcpy directly into the enum like you do with the uint32_t?
template <class Enum>
requires std::is_enum_v<Enum>
void deserialize(std::byte* addr, Enum& val)
{
    memcpy(&val, addr, sizeof(Enum));
}

There's no reason to write a separate overload per enum.

That looks proper thanks!

Well for one this is not a static cast, it's a reinterpret cast. You also kind of got lost in references. This will work:
using underlying_type = std::underlying_type_t<decltype(val)>;
deserialize(buf, *reinterpret_cast<underlying_type*>(&val));


Note that this will also emphasize how dangerous what you're doing is. A specialized serializer library is a much better choice here.
